# How can I solve this network problem that arose in my react project when using an aws rds?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-rds, network-protocols

Previously I was working on my project with a local database, but I have migrated to an aws database, I have already created my instance and everything seems to work properly (I am working on my backend with node.js, MySQL, express, and cross and Axios), the tests tell me that the connection is successful from the node.js console I have, but when I want to use my database from a visual interface, problems arise, since I get the following error when I try to do something that has to do with my database:
[Everything used to work fine with my local database, but with was, I have this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Uhf.jpg)

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // 
  
    Axios.post('http://dbmt.cqnwbmshskv1.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/login', { usuario, contra })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data === "login successful") {
          console.log("login successful");
          navigate("./Menu");
        } else {
          alert('INCORRECT DATA');
          setErrorMessage("Username or password incorrect");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setErrorMessage("Server Error");
      });
  };
```

This is my login code (part of it) I just change the URL part, then everything is the same as the good one about my aws connection it is alright, I already did a test and the connection was successful, but I don't know why I have this problem.

Honestly, I don't have much knowledge on the subject and there aren't many videos either, the only thing I've tried is to change the port in the URL, previously it was 3001, and I've removed it because that's how I saw it on the internet but it didn't solve the problem either, I made sure that my database was well connected, then it's not a connection problem or so I think, I really don't have much idea what else to try.

Comment: What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the Amazon RDS database? It should be permitting an inbound connection from the Security Group associated with your EC2 instance on port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make a POST request to a database directly from the client-side application?

The URL you are providing in the axios.post call is DB endpoint, which is incorrect.

The client-side app should typically interact with server-side app, which then communicates with the DB.

For the client side, your axios.post call would usually be to port 3001.

The server-side app would have an endpoint like:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  // Logic here to interact with AWS RDS
  // e.g., validate the username and password from req.body
});
```